# How do you use the Typescript compiler's Typechecker to get the declared (alias) type, rather than the resolved type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I realize this is somewhat obscure, but maybe someone else has run into this or knows the Typescript compiler well. I am processing Typescript files using Typescript's compiler API, based on examples like this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

Imagine I have a declared function like this in Typescript:

```
export type DateString = string;
export function parseDate(date: DateString): Date{
    let parsedDate = Date.parse(date);
    let retVal = new Date();
    retVal.setTime(parsedDate);
    return retVal;
}
```

In the examples linked above, you can see methods like this defined to extract information about symbols:

```
function serializeSymbol(symbol: ts.Symbol): DocEntry {
    return {
        name: symbol.getName(),
        type: checker.typeToString(checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(symbol, symbol.valueDeclaration))
    };
}
```

When you run `checker.typeToString(checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(symbol, symbol.valueDeclaration)` on the `date: DateString` symbol, instead of returning `DateString`, it returns `string`.  In other words, you don't get the declared type alias, but the fully resolved type. In my case, I'd like to know that the type of the `date` field is `DateString`. Is there an easy way to look up a parameter's declared type rather than its resolved type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't work because of "type interning." See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28197#issuecomment-434027046).

What works is to get the text of the `typeNode`. So basically get the text from the node. Here's a working example that you may be apply to your scenario:

```
// fileToAnalyze.ts
type DateString = string;
function myFunction(date: DateString) {
}

// main.ts
import * as ts from "typescript";
import * as path from "path";

const program = ts.createProgram([path.join(__dirname, "fileToAnalyze.ts")], { });
const file = program.getSourceFiles().filter(f => /fileToAnalyze/.test(f.fileName))[0];

const funcNode = (file.statements[1] as ts.FunctionDeclaration);
const parameterNode = funcNode.parameters[0];
console.log(parameterNode.type.getText(file)); // DateString
```

By the way, you might want to check out this library <strike>ts-type-info</strike> <strike>ts-simple-ast</strike> [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph) that I've been working on in case you haven't seen it.

Comment: Wow David! What a great answer. Much appreciated. And your library looks great. Time to go rip out my homegrown solution to do all this. :)